# Unable to import PostgreSQL database in Ubuntu

Tags: apt, postgresql

I need one help i need to import my database file to ubuntu using PostgreSQL.When i am checking my database its looking like below.

[image]

When i am trying to import my database file using the following command.

```
sudo psql sallon_test1</home/subhrajyoti/Sallon/sallon_test.sql
```

its giving me the following error.

[image]

```
psql fatal role root does not exist
```

I need to import database for `user1` username.Please help me to resolve this issue and import the database successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use the system user postgres to import your database.

> sudo su - postgres

or

> sudo -u postgres -i

Comment: Ok,I did as per you and when trying to import using same command its displaying to type password.after typing password its giving the error message `sorry try again`.Can you say me how to import the databe for `user1` i have already shown the screen shot in my post.

Answer (score 1):

Below commands imported database; please change directory as per your path,

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-177:/var/www/html/xyzapp$ sudo su - postgres

postgres@ip-10-0-0-177:~$ psql -U postgres covid19 < /var/www/html/xyzapp/Database/kan_structure.pgsql
```